# gpu is not recognized in minikube pod

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, minikube

Please help me... I am using GCP to conduct a deep learning project using GPUs.
My vm spec is :

- OS : Ubuntu 20.04
- minikube : v1.31.1
- docker-ce : 24.0.5
- GPU : T4
- nvidia graphics driver :535.54.03
- NVIDIA-SMI : 535.54.03
- CUDA Version: 12.2
- nvidia-docker : 2.13.0
- nvidia-container-runtime : 1.13.5
- nvidia-container-toolkit : 1.13.5
- kustomize : v3.2.0

I also have nvidia-device-plugin-daemonset.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UTen.png)
Despite having the following prerequisites, the GPU is not being detected in the pod like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGh6.png)

I have been struggling with this issue for a week now. If anyone can please help, I would be truly grateful.
Thank you.

And for some reason, when I start Minikube, whenever I make changes to the daemon.json file as

```
{
  "default-runtime": "nvidia",
  "runtimes": {
      "nvidia": {
          "path": "nvidia-container-runtime",
          "runtimeArgs": []
   }
  }
}
```

it reverts to the following

```
{
"exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs"],
"log-driver": "json-file",
"log-opts": {
        "max-size": "100m"
},
"storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
```

Could this be the reason?